# Lifting inequalities of integrals of random variables from a field to its sigma field

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Say $F_0$ is a field and we have a measure $\mu$ on $\sigma(F_0)$ and two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that $\int_A  X_1 d\mu \leq \int _A X_2 d\mu$ for all $A \in F_0$.

- When would the same inequality hold over all of $\sigma(F_0)$ too? It would be great to get to see some proofs about what is know in this direction!

---

I get an impression that this is likely to be true at least when $\mu$ is sigma-finite but I am not sure what the specifics are! At least sigma-finiteness does suffice if what were to be lifted were an equality and not an inequality!